Adjectives corresponding to nationalities
As far as I understand, nationalities in Japanese are expressed either using the name of the nation together with [人]{じん} to form an adjective, or directly using the name of the nation with the の particle. For example, to say "Chinese person", we can say either

中国[人]{じん}

or

中国の[人]{ひと}

I suppose the same holds for a generic term like 外国, which translates to "foreign country". So, I would either use 外国[人]{じん} or 外国の[人]{ひと}. I've found a sentence in my textbook, both written and spoken, which goes like:

この大学に外国[人]{じん}の先生が35[人]{にん}います。

So, is it incorrect to attach 外国 to 先生 (unlike it is for [人]{ひと}) saying

外国の先生

just like one says

外国の[人]{ひと}

or to use 中国[人]{じん} directly as an adjective (so without the particle の, that is 中国[人]{じん}先生). Probably English is leading me off track and this is not an adjective in Japanese (also, would it be a -い or -な adjective?), but even then I don't understand. Can you shed some light on this?
Incidentally, here's the audio. The sentence is at 0:37.

A more careful search lead me to this answer by the user naruto, which addresses my doubts, confirming what the user Arfrever mentioned in a comment in the answer by Daciu Barbat. Nonetheless, I shall write this answer for the sake of completeness, mutatis mutandis.
According to the answer above, the phrases

中国の先生、外国の先生、外国の人

correspond the meaning 1 (cf. answer above) of the particle の, that is affiliation/belonging. More schematically, in this specific case, if B is a country and A is a noun, A の B is B from/of A, (the choice between "from" and "of" ultimately depends on the meaning)(1)
On the other hand, the phrases

中国人の先生、外国人の先生

correspond to the meaning 2, that is state/description/apposition. Here the の particle seems to be the same as the copula である), so the literal translation would be more or less A teacher who is Chinese/a foreigner, which is more easily adapted as A Chinese/foreign teacher.
Finally, I will address this query, made in my original question:

or to use 中国人 directly as an adjective (so without the particle の, that is 中国人先生). Probably English is leading me off track and this is not an adjective in Japanese (also, would it be a -い or -な adjective?), but even then I don't understand.

As I understand, 中国人 is just a noun, not an adjective, so it can't be used to modify a noun by direct juxtaposition. This may confuse some learners because we translate it in English with an adjective:

田中さんは中国人です。

is usually translated as "Tanaka is Chinese." Probably "Tanaka is a Chinese person" is a better rendition to understand this point.

(1) As the other answer and the comments cleverly suggest, the phrase 中国の先生 - unlike the one below (中国人の先生) - is more generic. One possible interpretation is in terms of nationality (B **from** A), but is may also interpreted as relating B to A without necessarily speaking of nationality (B **of** A). In our case, teacher(s) of Japan, which are the teachers who work in Japanese and may not be Japanese citizens.

As mentioned in Daciu Barbat's answer, it's also worth considering the fact that if you use 中国の instead of 中国人の, the semantic relationship becomes ambiguous - it's no longer necessarily talking about race/nationality. For (slightly contrived) example, in a conversation about schools I could say アメリカの先生の何割が日本人ですか？ Obviously that アメリカ couldn't be アメリカ人

@Mindful I may expand my answer but I'm not sure I understand your example. I would still translate your sentence to "what percentage of american teachers are Japanese citizens?". I can't think of another interpretation of アメリカの先生 here, unless we're assuming that they can't have both nationalities; in such case, my translation would be wrong. Could you enlighten me?

Why not allow the interpretation "teachers of America" to mean "teachers of/の America" for the sake of statistics, as they belong to the current American teaching body, even if they are Japanese people (日本人), such as, for instance, a visiting Japanese professor?

Thank you @DaciuBarbat it's perfectly meaningful. I have to be honest, my mind was not considering that option in English either. Of course, teachers who work in America would be "teachers of America", which has a different meaning.

中国人、外国人, etc mean actually Chinese nationals, foreign nationals, etc. So 中国人の先生 is "teacher of chinese nationality", hence a Chinese teacher. 外国人の先生 is "teacher of foreign nationality", a foreign teacher. 中国の先生 is more generic, meaning teacher from/of/relating to China. The same for 外国人の先生。

According to jisho 中国人="Chinese person". How would you explain the difference with the claim in your answer?
Moreover, what about the situation 中国人先生? Is that even possible?

@Mr.Feynman For the purpose of translation of 中国人, "Chinese person" or "Chinese national" mean the same. What difference do you think there is? 中国人先生 would be a compound noun, and 中国人 is also grammatically a noun.

@Arfrever Yes, sorry. I was sloppy with what I meant. I wanted to say that 中国人 means "Chinese person", so why does 中国人の先生 mean "teacher of chinese nationality"? It's as if in this phrase 中国人 means "nationality", which is not stricly the same as "national"/"person".

@Mr.Feynman This の is Attributive form (連体形) of defective copular verb n- ("to be"), and can be translated as "who is, which is". So 中国人の先生 literally means "teacher, who is Chinese person".
